# How to concatenate values of a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to concat values column values in MySQL db but I get an error

> FUNCTION sales.STRING_AGG does not exist

```
SELECT
    city, 
    STRING_AGG(email,';') email_list
FROM
    sales.customers
GROUP BY
    city;
```

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `group_concat`

```
SELECT  city, 
        group_concat(email) email_list
FROM customers
GROUP BY city;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e49f7ebe2592ac99842d7e3f4e82cb85)

You can also order by inside of the group_concat() function like this:

```
group_concat(email order by email) email_list
```

Or change separator from default `,` to `;`

```
group_concat(email order by email desc separator ';') email_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?

```
SELECT city, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(email) email_list 
FROM sales.customers 
GROUP BY city;
```